# AWS Elasticsearch: How to move data from one index into another

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

It is known that AWS Elasticsearch put a lot of strange constrains on the normal Elasticsearch API.

I want to update the setting of my existing index in order to add a new analyzer. But it needs to close and reopen the index (since setting update is not allowed on active setting) which is not allowed by AWS Elasticsearch.

So I am thinking about creating a new index with new setting and moving the old data into new index.

My question is: how can I move data in one index into another easily on AWS Elasticsearch with Kibana dev tool?

Answer (score 3):

well you can do simply this from the sense plugin/ kibana dev tool ,this will copy all the data from the old index to new index

NOTE: first define setting and mappings for new index then run the following query.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old index_name" 
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new index_name"
  }
}
```